# How to display a number of different lines in a label using c#?

Tags: c#

I know how to display one line of text in a label using

thislabels.Text = "Hello";

But I want to be able to display a line of text each time an event happens, while also maintaining whats currently on display.

For example, I'm making a scoreboard and I want to print every time someone scores something like this..

```
Joe Smith scored 3 points
Joe Smith scored 5 points
...
Smith Joe scored 3 points
```

How do I do this? I'm not concerned with any of the formatting of how to display the text, I just want to know I can keep a running of events

Comment: try ``thislabels.Text+="\n"+event`` (remember to set to empty string initially)

Comment: I would recommend you not using a label if the text is going to change based on an event. i'd rather use a readonly textbox

Comment: In this case a ListBox is also good because of the scrollbars

Answer (score 4):

You could append a newline every time, some examples:

```
label.Text += $"{Environment.NewLine}YourTextHere";//String-interpolation
label.Text += String.Format("{0}YourTextHere", Environment.NewLine);
label.Text += Environment.NewLine + "YourText";
```

This could however get quite big, I suggest putting your `label` in a `panel` with the property `AutoScroll` to `true`, this way the panel is the max size of the label and instead of going off the `Form` it will make a scrollbar:

```
panel.AutoScroll = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
thislabel.Text += "Hello"

Hello

thislabel.Text += "\r\nWorld"

Hello
World
```